# How would I cause the fruit in the following code to repeat?

Tags: java, loops, animation, if-statement, statements

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import acm.graphics.GLabel;
import acm.graphics.GOval;
import acm.graphics.GPolygon;
import acm.graphics.GRect;
import acm.graphics.GRectangle;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class FruitCatcher extends GraphicsProgram {
    private static final int APPLET_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int APPLET_HEIGHT = 500;
    private static final int BUCKET_X = 250;
    private static final int BUCKET_Y = 500;
    private static final int BUCKET_SPEED = 10;
    private static final int BUCKET_SPEED2 = -10;
    final int WAIT = 10;

    GPolygon Bucket;
    GOval fruit;

    int time, score;
    GLabel scoreLbl;

    public void init() {
        setSize(APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT);

        time = 0;
        score = 0;

        scoreLbl = new GLabel("" + score);
        scoreLbl.setFont("SanSerif-BOLD-30");
        scoreLbl.setColor(Color.RED);
        add(scoreLbl, 2, 26);

        setSize(APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT);
        addKeyListeners();
    }

    public void run() {
        RandomGenerator random = new RandomGenerator();
        GRectangle fruitOval, bucketBox;

        boolean fruitDone = false;

        makeBucket();
        addFruit(random.nextInt(1, 3), random.nextInt(0, 300 - 20), 0);
        while (true) {
            fruit.move(0, 2);
            pause(WAIT);
            time = time + WAIT;

            fruitOval = fruit.getBounds();
            bucketBox = Bucket.getBounds();

            if (fruitOval.intersects(bucketBox) == true) {
                score++;
                remove(fruit);

                if(fruitOval.getY());


                // if the fruit is in the window
                // and the fruit is not touching the bucket
                // the fruit is touching the bucket
                // the fruit is not in the window
                /*
                 * if(if the fruit is in the window){ if(and the fruit is not
                 * touching the bucket){ }else(the fruit is touching the
                 * bucket){ } }else(the fruit is not in the window){ {
                 */

            }
        }

    }

    public void makeBucket() {
        Bucket = new GPolygon(BUCKET_X, BUCKET_Y);
        Bucket.addVertex(-60, 0);
        Bucket.addVertex(-70, -85);
        Bucket.addVertex(10, -85);
        Bucket.addVertex(0, 0);

        add(Bucket);
        Bucket.setFilled(true);
        Bucket.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    public void addFruit(int a, int x, int y) {

        switch (a) {
        case 1:
            fruit = new GOval(x, y, 10, 60);
            fruit.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            fruit.setFilled(true);
            add(fruit);
            break;
        case 2:
            fruit = new GOval(x, y, 20, 20);
            fruit.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            fruit.setFilled(true);
            add(fruit);
            break;
        case 3:
            fruit = new GOval(x, y, 30, 30);
            fruit.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            fruit.setFilled(true);
            add(fruit);
        }

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            if (Bucket.getX() > 0) {
                Bucket.move(-BUCKET_SPEED, 0);
            }
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            if (Bucket.getX() < APPLET_WIDTH) {
                Bucket.move(BUCKET_SPEED, 0);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What my code does so far is, I have a random fruit fall from the top. I also have a score set up in the corner. The fruit hits the bucket (as I move it with the arrows) and then disappears. However, few things:

1. The score doesn't go up.
2. I can't figure out for the life of me how to make another random fruit pop up on top.

I tried `if(fruit.getY();` Which gives me an error because it cannot convert from double to boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What my code does so far is, I have a random fruit fall from the top.
>   
> >I also have a score set up in the corner.
>   
> >The fruit hits the bucket (as I move it with the arrows) and then disappears.
>   
> >However, few things:
>   
> >    The score doesn't go up.
>   
> You might actually need to refresh **scoreLbl**, e.g. assign a new string to scoreLbl when you increment score.
>   
> Maybe something like
>
> ```
> scoreLbl.setLabel( "" + score);
> ```
>
> whenever you say
>
> ```
> score++;
> ```
>
> This seems like the documentation for GLabel:
>   
>    https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GLabel.html#setLabel%28String%29
>   
> I haven't worked with that class before so I'm not 100% sure it will work, but give it a try.
>   
>   
> >    I can't figure out for the life of me how to make another random fruit pop up on top.
>   
> >I tried if(fruit.getY(); Which gives me an error because it cannot convert from double to boolean.
>   
> This is a little trickier.
>   
> So... what happens if you generate another fruit after calling "removefruit();" ?
>   
> The modified code may could look like this....

```
if (fruitOval.intersects(bucketBox) == true) {
    score++;
    scoreLbl.setLabel( "" + score); // New.
    remove(fruit);
    addFruit(random.nextInt(1, 3), random.nextInt(0, 300 - 20), 0); // New.
}
```

As for this thing: if(fruitOval.getY())

fruitOval.getY() is going to return the fruit's numeric Y value, apparently a double.

Since if() expression wants a boolean, you could compare the fruit's Y value it to something... the comparison will answer true or false.  For example:

```
if( fruitOval.getY() > 50 ) { System.out.println("fruit beyond 50!"); }
```

I struggle with what you'd want to compare it to, 50 is just something I made up at random.

But I hope that gives you an idea of how to modify the code.

Happy coding and good luck :-)

Comment: Truly appreciate it. I was going to use the getY to make the fruit go to the top again. I tried the addFruit you posted and it didn't work which had me confused so I was going to trouble shoot and try something new. In my case, the problem was forgetting the 0 at the end.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out, looks like some fun programming.  If you found my answer helpful, please consider doing the accept thing ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ).